# Redux-form: Field value from state isn't submitted

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a field (source-file) in redux-form which is being updated by a change in the application state. The state value is being properly delivered to the field but when clicking submit, only the first field (name) is submitted (which I fill in interactively).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'; 
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { Link } from 'react-router'; 
import * as actions from '../../actions/job_actions'; 
import UploadPage from './upload_page';

const renderField = field => (
    <div>
      <label>{field.input.label}</label>
      <input {...field.input}/>
      {field.touched && field.error && <div className="error">{field.error}</div>}
    </div> );

class JobForm extends Component {

  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.createJob(formProps);  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
              <label>Title</label>
              <Field name="name" component={renderField} type="text" />
              <label>Input File</label>
              <Field name="source_file" component={() => {
                  return (
                    <div class="input-row">
                      <input type="text" value={this.props.uploadedFile} />
                    </div>
                  )
                }} />
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-
                primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    );   
  }; 
 }

const form = reduxForm({ form: 'JobForm' });

function mapStateToProps({uploadedFile}) { return { uploadedFile }; }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(form(JobForm));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want redux-form to include your field, then you'll need to render it as an actual field (as you do with your `renderField`).

If you don't want to treat it as an actual field, then the redux-form author suggests [injecting the values from state within your submit handler](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/711#issuecomment-191850962). Maybe something like this:

```
handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
  this.props.createJob({ ...formProps, source_file: this.props.uploadedFile} );
}
```

Comment: I want redux-form to include my field. Tried rendering it but it didn't solve the issue. The form is still submitted without it. I have changed the Field to this:  <Field name="source_file" component={renderFileField} type="text" />       and placed the following inside render() as otherwise I don't have access to "this.props.uploadFile":                                                                       const renderFileField = field => (
        <div>
          <label>{field.input.label}</label>
          <input {...field.input} value={this.props.uploadedFile}/>
        </div>
    );